# PYTHON/SFTP: Using get() to replace a file when it already exists

Tags: python, ftp, sftp

I'm trying to copy a file from a remote server to my local server. I am running into the issue where it will sometimes grab the file despite it already grabbing it before.
I want to be able to just overwrite/replace the file if it already exists. Is it possible to do so with the get() method?

```
with pysftp.Connection(
        host='hostname',
        username='user',
        private_key=key,
        cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    
        sftp.get(remotepath="file_path",
                    localpath="local_path",
                    preserve_mtime=True)
```

Comment: The `get` actually *overwrites/replaces the file if it already exists*. So what is your problem?

Answer (score -1):

**pysftp.Connection.get()** does not offer a local exist check, so you'll have to do that yourself.

For instance (reusing the pysftp import which makes the os module available):

```
with pysftp.Connection(
        host='hostname',
        username='user',
        private_key=key,
        cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
        
        if not pysftp.os.path.exists(local_path):
            sftp.get(remotepath="file_path",
                        localpath="local_path",
                        preserve_mtime=True)
```

*docs:*

```
 |  get(self, remotepath, localpath=None, callback=None, preserve_mtime=False)
 |      Copies a file between the remote host and the local host.
 |      
 |      :param str remotepath: the remote path and filename, source
 |      :param str localpath:
 |          the local path and filename to copy, destination. If not specified,
 |          file is copied to local current working directory
 |      :param callable callback:
 |          optional callback function (form: ``func(int, int)``) that accepts
 |          the bytes transferred so far and the total bytes to be transferred.
 |      :param bool preserve_mtime:
 |          *Default: False* - make the modification time(st_mtime) on the
 |          local file match the time on the remote. (st_atime can differ
 |          because stat'ing the localfile can/does update it's st_atime)
 |      
 |      :returns: None
 |      
 |      :raises: IOError
```